# Dynamic image in a GridView based on HiddenField

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a problem with a dynamic image in a grid.
I want to visualize a different image for each different Id in a HiddenField.

The code is:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewExample" runat="server" CellPadding="2" >
   <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField Visible="False">
           <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenId" runat="server" Value='<%#Bind("id") %>' />
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField>
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:LinkButton ID="ImageButtonLink" runat="server">
                   <asp:Image ID="image" runat="server" ImageUrl='DYNAMIC_URL' />
               </asp:LinkButton>
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>                    
</asp:GridView>
```

I tried with a method in ImageUrl.
The problem is that I used `ImageUrl="<%#test(<%#Bind("id") %>)%>"` and it doesn't work because I used two `<%#` and it reads ones.

The code of test is (of course Id is a int):

```
protected string test(int x) {
   if(x == 1)
        return "~/Images/black.png";
   else
        return "~/Images/white.png";
}
```

How can I set a different url for a different Id?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Following Code

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridViewExample" runat="server" CellPadding="2">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField Visible="False">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenId" runat="server" Value='<%#Bind("id") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="ImageButtonLink" runat="server">
                        <asp:Image ID="image" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("id").ToString().Trim()=="1"?"~/Images/black.png":"~/Images/white.png" %>' />
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: yes it works!Thank you very much!Also, I used it with four cases and four images and it works!
Eval("Id").ToString().Trim()=="1"?"~/Images/one.png":(Eval("Id").ToString().Trim()=="2"?"~/Images/two.png":(Eval("Id").ToString().Trim()=="3"?"~/Images/three.png":(Eval("Id").ToString().Trim()=="4"?"~/Images/four.png":"~/Images/error.png")))

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following (you don't need the second hash #):

```
  <asp:Image ID="image" runat="server" ImageUrl = '<%# test(Eval("Id")) %>' />
```

Or if you want to change it for every row, on [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of gridview do :

```
if(e.Row.Rowtype == DataControlType.DataRow)    
{
     Image imgage = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("Image");    
     image.IamgeURl =  //your URL;
}
```